# Modifying a possible repeated element only the first time in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 tables. One Owner can have None or multiple Item(s).

```
Item

id  name    owner_id (fk) 
1   alpha   1
2   beta    1


Owner

id   name     attrc 
1   owner1    complex_attr1
2   owner2    complex_attr2
```

I retrieve them separately from database as lists:

```
    for item in item_list:
        for owner in owner_list:
            if item.owner_id == owner.id:
              # I modify owner attributes    
              owner.attrc = modify_funct(attrc)
              item.owner = owner
```

I list `Items` in html, and for each `Item` I show some properties of the `Owner` of the `Item`. In the loop I make the `Owner` a property of the `Item` object; The thing is to show in html I need to modify some of the `Owner` raw db properties

so in html template creation I will have something like:

```
for item in item_list:
 <div>
   item.name
   <span> item.owner.name<span>
   <span> item.owner.attrc<span>
</div>
```

Because the `Owner with id 1` owns both `Item with id 1 and 2`, in the first iteration in loop, the `attrc` is modified, the second iteration in loop the 'attrc' is already modified, and the function doesn't found what is expected.

The solution is to loop/change the 'attrc' outside with another loop, and then loop item_list and owner_list, to do less loops ?

Comment: maybe store the references of modified owner references/ids in a `set` to call the modify_funct only once?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't need to know about specific items or match owners with items (`owner.attrc = modify_funct(attrc)` doesn't involve items) so you just want to find owners that own at least one item?

Comment: I list  items in html, and for each item some properties about the owner of the item. In the loop I make the owner a property of the item object; The thing is to show in html I need to modify some of the owner raw db properties

Comment: That only leaves me more confused. Add some more context to your question with code.

Comment: So are you saying you want `item.owner.attrc` to be different for different items even if they have the same owner? You can't have that, just attach the attribute directly to the owner, e.g. `item.owner_attrc`.

Comment: Owner is an Object, that can have multiple properties, I modify just one attribute. I can't attach the Owner attribute to item directly(templating stuff). But I attached the owner as an Item property.

Comment: @AlexHall I don't want item.owner.attrc to be different. In my code in modified the Owner 'attrc' in the first loop, on the second loop I try to modify again, and again (if is the same Owner). I don't want to do that. Once modified , for the next Item if is the same Owner don't modify 'attrc'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188885/discussion-between-alex-hall-and-user3541631).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most efficient solution, but it's the most similar to your existing code:

```
for owner in owner_list:
    if any(item.owner_id == owner.id for item in item_list):
        owner.attrc = modify_funct(attrc)
```

Answer (score 0):

More efficient solution using a set comprehension:

```
owner_ids = {item.owner_id for item in item_list}
for owner in owner_list:
    if owner.id in owner_ids:
        owner.attrc = modify_funct(attrc)
```

Comment: I update the question to be more clear, so I need to match the item and owner, not only change the property for owner